# Is a or free SAT formula NP complete?

Tags: turing-machines, np-complete, logic, np-hard, p-vs-np

Let $L$ be the languague which contains all satisfiable formulas which do not have the or symbol $\lor $.
Or more precise $$L=\{\phi | \phi \text{ is a satisfable formula which is only using the junctors $\lor$ and $\neg$ }\}$$

Is $L$ NP-Complete  ? I think it is NP-Complete. I can at least show that is in NP. A nondeterministic polynomial time machine can guess an assignment to a given formula φ and if the
assignment satisfies φ it can simply check if the formula is using $\lor$ . If no, accept. If yes, reject.

Next I would need to make a polynomial time reduction from a $NPC$ problem to $L$. I think $3-SAT$ would be a good starting point. But I dont know how to convert a satisfable 3-CNF formula into a satisfable OR free formula.

Comment: You know that $A \lor B = \lnot (\lnot A \land \lnot B)$, right?

Comment: No, I did not. But it seems logical. Thank you. So all I need to do is to transform each connection between two literals A and B into $\neg(\neg A \land \neg B$) ? I wonder how this is going to work with 3 literals. But lets assume that I can transform it, why should that transformation be in polynomial time ?

Comment: $A \lor B \lor C = \lnot (\lnot A \land \lnot B \land \lnot C)$, and this is obviously constant time. Maybe it would help if you pick up some more knowledge about logic.